# Inserting Multiple Records with a single query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am insering multiple records using `myqsli_multi_query`. But before insert, I want to check if these record(s) exist(s) before inserting into the database

Comment: Have you heard of using `WHERE NOT EXISTS`?  Update your question with your current `INSERT` query along with what your definition of a duplicate is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in each query.
Refs : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: This would require the proper keys being setup...which perhaps is exactly what the OP should be doing, or maybe not.